# Rspec: how to test partial render with locals and params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, bdd, rspec-rails

I am trying to test this part of controller with Rspec:

```
def popup_company
  if params[:partial].present?
    render partial: "popup_company/pages", locals: { tab_filter: params[:tab_filter] }
  end
end
```

Here is my controller spec to test the part mentioned above:

```
controller.should_receive(:render).with({
:partial => 'popup_company/pages',
:locals => {tab_filter: params[:tab_filter]}
})
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `params'
```

Guys, can you, please, tell me what I should change to overcome this error. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So params[:tab_filter] is in your request, so it's presumably in your get.  That is, you have something like:

```
get :popup_company, tab_filter: 'XXXXX', partial: 'YYYYY'
```

in your spec.  You should create a variable, random value for the tab_filter param and use that to validate the appropriate value is being passed to render.  Something like

```
tab_filter = SecureRandom.hex(10)
get :popup_company, tab_filter: tab_filter, partial: 'YYYYY'
controller.should_receive(:render).with({
  partial: 'popup_company/pages',
  locals: { tab_filter: tab_filter } })
```

Alternately you could use a `render_template('popup_company/pages')` spec to confirm that the template is being rendered, and test for the tab filter based on the content of the rendered view.

Answer (score 0):

Your `params` is on the spec-side code; it's just trying to be a local variable. Put in whatever you expect `params[:tab_filter]` to contain.

And, in general, you should not write tests - oops I mean "examples" - that merely repeat what the code says. You don't care your controller calls a partial; you care that the controller responds with HTML containing such-and-so values.